# The Blog appears two times in breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs, blog

We just started a new website and installed a Blog module. However I can see that the word Blog appears two times in the breadcrumbs.

Example here : http://www.muelltrennen24.com/blog/mull-richtig-trennen-biotonne

What can be the issue? I only have one category named Blog..

Many thanks
Razvan

Answer (score 0):

The first link goes to the landing page for the blog which shows all posts: http://www.muelltrennen24.com/blog

The second link goes to the blog category which only shows posts in that category:
http://www.muelltrennen24.com/category/blog which is a completely different page

You should rename your category to something better so it doesn't show blog twice.